# wp_pagination not displaying at top of page

Tags: plugins, pagination

I've installed the wp_pagination plugin and it appears to be working fine *at the bottom of the page*, however, the pagination is not displaying at the top of the page. Below is the template code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Press
*/
get_header(); ?>
    <div id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">
            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php wp_title(); ?></h1>
            </header>
            <?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
                wp_paginate('range=4&anchor=2&nextpage=Next&previouspage=Previous');
            } ?>
            <?php
             query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'cat' => 16, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) ); 
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();
             ?>
            <div class="news-dir">
                <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h3>
                    <?php 
                    global $more;    // Declare global $more (before the loop).
                    $more = 0;       // Set (inside the loop) to display content above the more tag.
                    the_content("More...");
                    ?>
            </div>
            <?
            endwhile;
            ?>

            <?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
                wp_paginate('range=4&anchor=2&nextpage=Next&previouspage=Previous');
            } ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

Why isn't it working at the top?

MTIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query_posts()` overwrites the original query, and the pagination gets the original before the `query_posts()` call and the changed after it.

Solution: Don’t use `query_posts()`, filter `pre_get_posts` instead. We have [tons of examples](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=pre_get_posts) for that on our site. :)

Here is some pseudo code (meaning: not tested).

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_58843_list_cat_16' );

function wpse_58843_list_cat_16( $query )
{
    // make sure this matches your template’s file name.
    // See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template
    if ( ! is_page_template( 'press.php' ) )
    {
        return $query;
    }

    $query->set( 'cat',            16 );
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );
    $query->set( 'post_type',      'post' );

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I can see the problem now, but I don't understand how to use `pre_get_posts` to get the posts. I need to write a function for that?

Comment: @circey I have added some sample code and a link to related questions with more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Put this:

```
<?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
                wp_paginate('range=4&anchor=2&nextpage=Next&previouspage=Previous');
            } ?>
```

just before this line:

```
<div class="news-dir">
```

Comment: That just means that there is pagination within the `while` statement, and creates a pagination area within each and every "news-dir" div.

Comment: Shoot! didn't think it through. The way you are trying should work fine... read toscho's answer above. could work...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your HTML source ?

Maybe you should check the css and determine that there is no problem with the visibility of generated HTML if it appears on page source.

Comment: Yes, I should've mentioned it in my post, sorry. Source shows the navigation div as `<div class="navigation"></div>`, ie. it's empty. Can't see how it could be a CSS issue because the pagination displays without any problems at the bottom of the page.